# Tweepy only lets me get 100 results, how do I get more? I've read about pagination but don't quite understand it

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I'm working with the Twitter API v2 with Tweepy, and I'm trying to get all of Elon Musk's tweets from the past year. `client.get_users_tweets("44196397", end_time="2022-03-31T11:59:59Z", exclude=['retweets', 'replies'], start_time="2021-03-31T11:59:59Z")`, and this code only gives me 10 results, and the limit parameter only lets me use 100 as the max, obviously Elon Musk has tweeted a lot more in the past year.

How do I get more? In the Tweepy documentation I saw the parameter of pagination, and pagination as its own function but don't quite understand it (I'm assuming pagination is going to be the solution).

I tried reading the documentation but didn't understand much. The only relevant code is there, please let me know if you need anything else.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `tweepy.Paginator` is very easy to use. Basically, you give it the method and the arguments that you want to use, and you then just have to iterate through it.

```py
paginator = tweepy.Paginator(
    client.get_users_tweets,               # The method you want to use
    "44196397",                            # Some argument for this method
    end_time="2022-03-31T11:59:59Z",       # Some argument for this method
    exclude=['retweets', 'replies'],       # Some argument for this method
    start_time="2021-03-31T11:59:59Z",     # Some argument for this method
    max_results=100,                       # How many tweets per page
    limit=5                                # How many pages to retrieve
)

for page in paginator:
    print(page)
    print(page.data)                       # The tweets are here
    print(page.meta)                       # The count etc. are here
    print(page.includes)                   # The includes are here
```

If you only want the tweets, you can even ask Tweepy to flatten the pages:

```py
paginator = tweepy.Paginator(
    client.get_users_tweets,               # The method you want to use
    "44196397",                            # Some argument for this method
    end_time="2022-03-31T11:59:59Z",       # Some argument for this method
    exclude=['retweets', 'replies'],       # Some argument for this method
    start_time="2021-03-31T11:59:59Z",     # Some argument for this method
    max_results=100                        # How many tweets asked per request
)

for tweet in paginator.flatten(limit=250): # Total number of tweets to retrieve
    print(tweet)
```

And if you want as much tweets as possible, you can remove the limit.

But in that case, don't forget the handle the rate limit ([see Twitter doc](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/rate-limits)):

```py
paginator = tweepy.Paginator(
    client.get_users_tweets,               # The method you want to use
    "44196397",                            # Some argument for this method
    end_time="2022-03-31T11:59:59Z",       # Some argument for this method
    exclude=['retweets', 'replies'],       # Some argument for this method
    start_time="2021-03-31T11:59:59Z",     # Some argument for this method
    max_results=100                        # How many tweets asked per request
)

try: 
    for tweet in paginator.flatten():      # Default to inf
        print(tweet)
except tweepy.RateLimitError as exc:
    print('Rate limit!')
```

A few more points:

- For Twitter API V1 endpoints, you will have to use `tweepy.Cursor` instead.
- Every limit that you set is a requested maximum, Twitter can send you less data.
- I have seen many developpers say that they faced consistency errors when they tried to access Elon Musk data. I don't know why or even if this is still the case, but keep it in mind.